# Can't modify innertext of each htmlelement

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding a proxyleecher, but instead of coding different functions for each site it uses crawler. Now I have some page displaying proxiy list loaded in webbrowser control, so I need to add ":" to each proxy, so I will have ip:port instead of ipport and than I can use regexes to get the proxies:

```
            For Each cur As HtmlElement In brwsr.Document.All
            If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(cur.InnerText, "(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}") Then
               cur.InnerText = cur.InnerText & ":"
           End If
       Next
```

but this don't work, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using the asci code for colon?

```
 cur.InnerText = cur.InnerText & "&#58;"
```